# Alternative Way to Import SQL to MYSQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql

Before, I asked a question in here how to linked the SQL to MYSQL. It was a success and I can also query from it. The problem is upon searching why "I can't find SQL SERVER AGENT" in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO EXPRESS EDITION is because it is "EXPRESS". All the ideas that I will be working using SQL Scheduler will unable to continue because the management studio that I have is not capable of it.

Can I have alternative way where in I can create scheduler or scheduled time for Transferring the SQL to MYSQL.

Thank you.

Comment: Windows scheduled tasks will probably work best for you.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, do you think database migration using mysql workbench plus task scheduler is possible?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik also What language do i need to implement in scheduled task if that is your comment?

Comment: "Import SQL to MySQL" does not make sense. SQL is a _query language_ that is used to work with the database. MySQL _uses_ SQL just like any other relational database. You can't "import" or "transfer" a language into a database server

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11063854/470530) could be of help. For scheduling, you'll have to do what is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201189/470530). You can connect to an Express instance using MySQL WorkBench as outlined [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard-connection.html), but you can't [schedule jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103858/how-to-schedule-a-job-in-mysql-workbench).

Also, have you considered using [ODBC](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1eeed552-449e-4ffe-bb55-3e87cee1ccbc/odbc-drivers-for-connecting-to-sqlexpress?forum=sqlexpress) to connect and send the data to another (i.e. MySQL) server. You can schedule many of these systems also!

Or try [JDBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server) using [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) or [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/)? Personally, I can recommend SQuirreL SQL! If you want to schedule a job using Java, try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034739/470530)! Just be aware that your dumps may not be internally consistent unless you are careful about your transactions!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Pentaho Data Integration, community edition. It is free and will suit your task perfectly. You will need JDBC drivers for both SQL Server and Mysql, and create a very simple transformation with a table input and a table output. You design and test your transformation in a tool called Spoon, then schedule a command line tool called Pan to run in.